# How to get a 2-D map matrix by length and width 1-D array in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Could I find a function in numpy achieved generating a 2-D map matrix by length and width array

for example, The length and width array of the rectangle:

```
length_point =[1, 2, 3]
width_point =[4, 5]
```

`shape_length=(n,)` `shape_width=(m, )`

then got `result_shape=(n*m, 2)`，the pairs of point in result represents the point in the rectangle ， just like latitude and longitude in map

```
result_point =[[1, 4], 
               [1, 5], 
               [2, 4], 
               [2, 5], 
               [3, 4], 
               [3, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach, which involves three Numpy functions, hence potentially not what you are looking for, but it still does the job:

```
>>> np.column_stack((np.repeat(length_point, len(width_point)),
                     np.tile(width_point, len(length_point))))
array([[1, 4],
       [1, 5],
       [2, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 5]])
```

[repeat](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) repeats the elements, while [tile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) repeats the array, and [column_stack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) is used to generate the desired concatenation.